# Ionic list and href delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building straight up from "$ ionic start myApp sidemenu" and deploy directly to Android.
However, when I tap on the playlist page e.g: tap on "Indie", I feel like there's 300ms delay before the page start to change.

This will be even worse, if the next page have img tag or any other stuff.

I understand that ionic should already have removed 300ms delay. Am I doing something wrong? I did not change anything, so the code is using href. Should I use ng-click instead?

I'm using the latest ionic v 1.0.0 "uranium-unicorn"

Comment: I Think you should go through this official Doc. http://blog.ionic.io/hybrid-apps-and-the-curse-of-the-300ms-delay/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the fragmented and outdated android webview (since the webview is used to render the app). You will get pretty bad performance on most android devices, UNLESS you build with the cross engine. I have one company app and on personal app in the play store and the only way we managed to get good performance on android was building with crosswalk. 
See This: http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/

Comment: I thought, ionic already removed the 300ms delay, and crosswalk is not suggested? I'm using Nexus 5, so browser should be the latest.

Comment: they did remove the delay, but the latest android browser engine can have lag issues, just in android 5 did they start updating the webview through the store. Mostly animations and transitions will lag. Crosswalk with dramatically increase the performance.